# Angular JS ng-repeat element does not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to display a list of products and be able to click on them to get more informations about them.

My list of products is stored in a service named: "productsServices"

I got an html page who display all my products and an other who display details for 1 product. Each html page have their own controller.

When I update a product in my detail page, the changement is done in my productsServices but are not validated in my global product view.

```js
(function ()
{
    angular.module('app').service('productsServices', ['$http', '$q', ProductsServices])
    that = this
    
    that.products           = /*arrayOfData*/;
    that.getProducts        = function () {
                                return that.products;
                              }
})();


(function ()
{
    angular.module('app').controller('ProductsController', ['$http', '$q',  'productsServices', ProductsController])
    
    that                   = this
    that.products          = productsServices.getProducts;
    
    that.showDetail        = function (item) {
                                $state.go('menu.product', { myParam: item });
                             }
})();
```

```html
<!--Global HTML page-->
<ion-content id="content" class="has-header has-subheader" delegate-handle="myScroll">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="product in that.products() track by product.ProductId" href="#" ng-click="that.showDetail({{product}})">
                <div class="innerProd">
                  <img id="productPicture" name="productPicture" ng-src='data:image/png;base64,{{product.ThumbnailPhoto}}'></div>
                <div class= "innerProd">
                    <p>{{product.Name}}</p>
                    <p>{{product.Price}}$</p>
                    <ion-option-button class="button button-assertive"
                                        ng-click="doDelete({{product}})">
                        Supprimer
                    </ion-option-button>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="moreDataCanBeLoaded()" icon="ion-loading-c" on-infinite="loadMoreData()" distance="100%">
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

So when I check the product sended in the "that.showDetail" method, it's the old product who is sended even if the product have been updated in the services.

I'm not english so sorry for language mistakes in my sentence ^^'

Thank in advance for your help ^^'

Comment: that.products           = "arrayOfData"; ?

Comment: `angular.module('app').service('ProductsController', ['$http', '$q',  'productsServices', ProductsController])` 
This line looks not ok, are trying to create a service named "ProductsController"

Comment: I don't get how the global html page could be noticed of any change from server or other pages. You would like that "that.products()" would be automatically updated without reloading global page right ?

Comment: that.products = an array of data

Comment: In fact, the "details product page" where i dod the change and the page where all the product are displayed arn't the same :)

display page -> click -> go to detail page -> update -> return to display page

Comment: My bad @abhijith , I did a bad copy/past of my code, just edited it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've find the ansewer to my question, I've replace the parameter that I'm sending to my "that.showDetail" function. I'm no more sending the object directly, but the index of my item.

```js
<ion-item ng-repeat="product in that.products() track by product.ProductId" href="#" ng-click="that.showDetail({{$index}})">
```

I guess that angular doesn't update injected in a ng-click call ^^'

Thank you for your time guys